# Jenkinsfile Pipeline do something when some checked-in file is changed / newly checked out / run in a fresh node

Tags: docker, jenkins, dockerfile, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to find a way to run some optional code in case a specific file is changed / newly checked out / run in a fresh node.

Specifically I'm trying to rebuild a Dockerfile which is used for the following build-steps only whenever the Dockerfile that's checked in actually changes.

Any pointers are much appreciated!